# js main thread get samples from AudioWorkletNode

Tags: javascript

How do you transfer data in AudioWorkletNode to the main thread?
in createScriptProcessor, We can use an event handler to record the samples from the microphone. but now, this method is deprecated.

I really do not want to change much of my project code.

So, I need to get samples from AudioWorkletNode. How I can do this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Your AudioWorkletNode has a [`.port`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioWorkletNode/port) property which is a [MessagePort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MessagePort). From the main thread you can add a  `"message"` event listener there, and from the Worklet you'll `postMessage()` whatever you want to share with the main thread.

Note that for better perfs you could also use a [SharedArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SharedArrayBuffer) which would be accessible by both contexts simultaneously.